# Not able to store data from api to variable in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am making login form for my app. After integration of api successfully i was trying to retrieve my email and password for login authentication but the process i'm using is not getting the data as i tried `log.v` to check whether desired data is being stored in variable or not.

Sample of Json data:

```
{
  "Email": "shayam@gmail.com",
  "Password": xxcctt,
  "Name": "shayam",
  "Phone": "987654321"
}
```

Login.java

```
package com.example.android.bet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private Button login;
Context context;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "Usergrant" ;
public static final String User = "userKey";
public static final String Pass = "passKey";
String uid,upass;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private final static String restURL="XXXXXXX";
Message msg = new Message();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    context=this;
    setupVariables();



}

Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.arg1==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "email id or password invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Print Toast or open dialog
        }
        return false;
    }
});

private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {


        String apiurl=restURL+"xxxEmail="+uid+"&Password="+upass;
        Log.v("URL Generated", apiurl);
        String betJsonStr=null;
        try {

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(apiurl);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }
                betJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v("json",betJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Didn't get data", "Error", e);
            }

            try {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(betJsonStr);

                String email,pasw;
                email=jObject.optString("Email").toString();
                pasw= jObject.optString("Dealer").toString();

                Log.v("email and",email+" "+pasw);

                if(uid.equals(email)&&upass.equals(pasw))
                {
                    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(User, uid);
                    editor.putString(Pass, upass);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent menu=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(menu);
                }
                else
                {

                    msg.arg1=1;
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }



            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception arised", "error", e);
        }
        //Do some work
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        //Print Toast or open dialog
    }
}

public void authenticateLogin(View view)
{
    uid=username.getText().toString();
    upass=password.getText().toString();
    new CustomTask().execute((Void[])null);

}

private void setupVariables()
{


    username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    username.setText("");
    password.setText("");

}
}
```

Comment: Consider using libraries like "Ion" or "android-async-http". It will save you time and effort since you won't have to deal with Http connections on your own and since JSON parsing will be performed automatically.

Comment: have you checked the `apiurl` by a browser? Make sure that the URL works

Comment: yup its perfectly working

Comment: Dogcart i ll implement it but at present i need to know what i'm not doing right...

Comment: In this example you don't call `authenticateLogin(..)`, did you forget it in this example? Also what exception message is thrown? I recommend you to use well tested libraries for http and/or api work. My preferred one is okhttp - Links here: [okhttp wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki) and [example code](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-OkHttp)

Comment: Does your app have the INTERNET permission?

Comment: yes i'm able to get the data of api in betJsonStr variable, as it is being displayed in the logcat

Comment: So, JSON parsing is the problem then? And there are no exceptions thrown? Btw,  the JSON sample you've posted is invalid, it has an extra comma in the end :-P

Comment: Nope there is no error or exception... Yup i think so json parsing is the problem.... and now is it okay :P